# redirecting www and non-www to www2 subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

This is the code I currently have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www2.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and this redirects www.domain.com to www2.domain.com properly. I want the non-www to redirect to like ^www.(.*)$ [NC] does since it keeps urls intact and just let them sit on www2.domain.com/whatever instead.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www2.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www2.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works well, what if we only wanted to redirect the domain name to www2 for example we just want to redirect www.domain.com but not www.domain.com/folder?